# Second monitor has vertical separation 14.04 on Thinkpad T410

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, thinkpad

I have a ThinkPad T410. After a recent update the second monitor (displayport) get a vertical separation in the first half and the cursor is quite slow. This looks something like this

[image: screen separation]

When the cursor enters the second Monitor it enters it at the separation. The left part is accessible via the right edge of the monitor.
This issue does not appear in any other OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update to 14.10 solved this problem for me. Not really satisfying, but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it accidently, changed the order of your screens. Go to screen settings and change the order.

Comment: This does not work. Also, I think you misunderstand. This picture above is a single monitor, that is cut in two. The left part is not part of my internal display, which is situated to the left(not seen in picture). When I place the external display in "screen settings" anywhere else, the display gets also cut in parts. Deleting .config/monitor.xml did not work either.

Comment: You could try to change the screen resolution, to a higher value.